# Cordova is not recognized

Tags: android, node.js, git, cordova

I have been trying for hours now to set-up PhoneGap.
I have been trying to get the navigator.notification.alert to work. I have been doing research and to no avail, nothing seems to be working.
I am using the npm install -g phonegap. It works with a few warnings and skipping a few things due to not having the requirements for making certain apps, such as IOS apps. 
So I type:

> npm install -g phonegap

and it works, then I type:

> phonegap create my-app

it doesn't work because phonegap is not recognized...
So then I typed:

> cd AppData
>     cd roaming cd npm

and then I type the

> phonegap create my-app

and it is successful!
I am wondering how I can do the phonegap command anywhere?
I have my environmental path PATH set to:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

and it still does not work unless I cd to the npm folder.
I have a app created already and I am trying to import the navigator.notification.alert plugin because my current code is not recognizing it. My friends told me that I have to import it through the

> phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs

so I am trying to do that!
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try the following ;  1) sudo npm cache clear
2) npm install -g phonegap

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I had to restart my computer. @shamaleyte

Comment: Ok so , which one was the solution :) ?   the commands that I suggested or restarting your computer  , or both?